# Check string for palindrome without INT 21h in emu 8086

Tags: assembly, x86-16, emu8086

I am working on an assignment for my computer architecture class, and I don't understand assembly all that well. I'm supposed to take a string input from keyboard and check whether it's a palindrome. I am not allowed to use `INT 21h`. I wrote the program as `db string value` rather than keyboard input but I still can't get my `CMP` to work properly. I'm pretty sure I am doing this wrong. Hopefully someone can help.

```
#make_COM#

include emu8086.inc


org 100h

jmp init       

  msg    db      "kayak",0          

init:
  Mov   SI,5
  mov   di,0
start: 

  mov  al,msg[si]
  dEC si
  inc di 

  mov  ah ,0eh
  int 10h  
  cmp si, -1
  jg start

check:

  mov al, msg[si]
  mov ah, msg[di]
  cmp al, ah
  jmp notpalin
  inc si
  dec di
  cmp si, 5
  jl check

palin:

  call pthis
  db "This is a palindrome", 0
  jmp stop

notpalin:

  call pthis
  db "This is not a palindrome", 0
  jmp stop

stop:
  mov     ah, 0 
  int     16h      ; wait for any key....
  ret ; return to operating system.

DEFINE_PTHIS
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- You need to start the `SI` register at 4 in stead of 5. With the number 5 you proces the NULL character that you don't want displayed with the BIOS Teletype function.
- Your program begins the *check* part will a `SI` register that contains -1. That's clearly not a correct memory reference for `mov al, msg[si]`.
- When you compare 2 characters, you need to use a conditional jump. You used a jump that always jumps!

  ```
  cmp al, ah
  jNE notpalin
  ```
- You can stop checking as soon as the indexes `SI` and `DI` have crossed each other.

The solution:

```
    mov si, 0
    mov di, 4
check:
    mov al, msg[si]
    mov ah, msg[di]
    cmp al, ah
    jne notpalin
    inc si
    dec di
    cmp si, di
    jb  check
```

Comment: Oh wow, I was alot closer then I realized. Oversight mistakes. Thanks for your solution @Sep Roland, helped me understand where I was going wrong.